Adding a morphism verifying a commutative diagram in a category
Suppose we have a category $C$, two objects $A$ and $B$ of $C$, and two morphisms $f:A\to A$ and $g:B\to B$. Now, I would like to construct a new category $C_{f,g}$, and a functor $F_{f,g}:C\to C_{f,g}$ such that the objects of $C$ and $C_{f,g}$ are the same, and the functor is the identity on objects, but in $C_{f,g}$ we adjoint a new morphism $\phi_{f,g}: A\to B$ in such a way that $\phi_{f,g}\circ f= g\circ \phi_{f,g}$. Is there a general construction that allows me to do it?
For example, if $f$ and $g$ are the identity morphisms, then what we are doing is adding just a morphism $\varphi$ "freely": the new category must have morfisms of the form
$$h_0\circ \varphi\circ h_1\circ \varphi\circ\cdots \circ \varphi\circ h_s $$
where the $h_s$ are morphisms in $C$, $s\ge 0$, whenever the morphisms can be composed (so, for example, if $s=1$, then $h_0:D\to A$ and $h_1:B\to E$, for some $D$, $E$ in $C$).
But if $f$ or $g$ are not the identity, we must identify some morphisms in $C_{f,g}$ in a compatible way, so we need to do some sort of quotient with respect to some "congruence" generated by $\phi_{f,g}\circ f \sim g\circ \phi_{f,g}$.
Can someone give me a good reference where to look at this?

You can express your construction as a pushout; then see this question.

The literature on this topic (colimits of categories explained in an elementary way) is quite sparse, which is why I wrote up Bicategorical colimits of tensor categories a while ago. Corollary 4.3 includes what you want, namely, that $\mathbf{cat}$ has all $2$-categorical colimits.
To freely adjoin a morphism $A \to B$, we take the $2$-categorical pushout $C \sqcup_{\{A,B\}} \{0 < 1\}$. To enforce some relations between morphisms (such as your one, but one can really take anything), take the classical quotient category by the smallest congruence containing the relation.
